Apex call returns successfully after errror, resulting in issues
I have an Apex call which causes an error (ENTITY_IS_DELETED, but it doesn't matter which error it is). I might be able to fix that error, but now it somehow also returns successfully anyway, so the client is confused.
Both the server and the client seem off, as follows.
// MyClass
public static void apexCall()
{
    // some code
    // --> generates error
    // return true; // -> Returns true anyways! This is the problem
}

In LWC, I call Apex. Now it catches the error, but then still proceeds to read the result anyway, which it shouldn't! It should stop.
console.log( '1' );

apexCall( { 
    var1: myVar
} ).then((result) =>
{
    console.log( '2 ' + result );

    // ..
))
.catch((error) =>
{
    log( 'x', this );

    console.error( error );
});

The log goes unexpectedly from the error to logging the new result (true):
1
x
2 true


It seems that there was an issue where the user was able to press the button twice, with calls conflicting each other. I implemented a way to disable the button until it completed its task.
